# use jquery to remove element from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form with multiple div elements like this

```
<div>
<label for="id">text</label>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="">
</div>
<div>
<label for="id1">text</label>
<input type="text" name="id1" id="id1" value="">
</div>
```

i use .post to validate some fields before submit
if the input failed validation i add a span element to the parent div

```
$('#id').parent('div:first').append('<span class="error">error message</span>');
<div>
<label for="id">text</label>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="">
    <span class="error">error message</span>
</div>
```

else i want to remove the span from the div and i tried

```
$('#id').parent('div:first').remove('.error');
$('#id').parent('div:first').remove('span');
```

but doesn't work
any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
 $('#id').nextAll('span.error').remove();
```

This would remove all the  with class error following the input

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/H5sDC/

Comment: not sure about nextAll (not familiar with that guy) but looks like the solution i was thinking bout, just remove .error

Comment: nextAll selects alle the siblings following the elements so that you have more than one error message all of them are removed

Comment: right on. just not familiar with it. i would've just dont $(".error").remove();